# Create a public SSH key from the private key?

Tags: ssh, encryption, public-key, private-key

Let's suppose I have a SSH key, but I've deleted the public key part. I have the private key part. Is there some way I can regenerate the public key part?

Answer (score 408, accepted):

Use the -y option to ssh-keygen:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

From the 'man ssh-keygen'

```
 -y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an
         OpenSSH public key to stdout.
```

Specify the private key with the -f option, yours might be dsa instead of rsa.  The name of your private key probably contains which you used.  The newly generated public key should be the same as the one you generated before.

Comment: Why the "-t dsa"? Mayge the OP's key is rsa? I'd get rid of -t and instead use a -f.

Comment: Good point, updated accordingly

Comment: yeah mine originally was RSA.

Comment: On Mac OSX 10.9.3 Mavericks I'm getting 'load failed' after running the command. How do I solve this?

Comment: I think you might take this one step further with the -N parameter in case the private key is password protected: `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y -N "$PASSWORD" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: @ken - surely it's a bit of a risk to enter your password at the shell prompt like that (it will be kept in the shell history, etc.), let alone storing it as an environment variable ($PASSWORD)?

Comment: @RobertMuil  It's ok, don't worry. For one thing, unless  you `export`, other processes cannot see the variable. And you can use `read -s PASSWORD`  to enter it without storing in shell history.

Comment: Just saved me from creating new key pair by mistake reverted < with > on pb copy and boom key lost cat returned empty

Comment: @kubanczyk - the password would still be visible as a process when it was exported, so you're correct that the actual usage of the password would be safer, but the added steps before hand reduce this added security substantially!  Much better to enter the password interactively.

Answer (score 9):

*Solution is specifically for users using Windows*

Tool Used:

- Puttygen (PuTTY Key Generator)
- WinSCP

Steps to perform:

1. Open PuTTY Key Generator.
2. Load your private key (`*.ppk` file).
3. Copy your public key data from the "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH  authorized_keys file" section of the PuTTY Key Generator
   and paste the key data to the "authorized_keys" file (using notepad) if you want to use it.

Snapshot showing portions of Puttygen to focus:

[image: Snapshot showing portions of Puttygen to focus]

Comment: Further reading: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53553/how-do-i-retrieve-the-public-key-from-a-ssh-private-key/700275#700275

Comment: Puttygen can also 'import' OpenSSH (really OpenSSL-legacy) and SSHCOM format privatekeys. And although originated on Windows, it has also been ported to Unix, and the Unix version of `puttygen` is a commandline (not GUI) program; see e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/1/puttygen

Comment: You cab get PuTTY and PuTTY tools on Linux too.