# Create a public SSH key from the private key? Is an `ssh-ed25519` public key unrecoverable?

Tags: ssh-keygen

I want to recover my `ssh` public key from my private key. I am aware of [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/52287/1002705) but it doesn't seem to work for me. When I run the command suggested `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/my_key -y > ~/.ssh/my_key.pub` I only get the algorithm `ssh-ed25519` and an `ssh` fingerprint not the full public key. What am I missing?

I tried making a new key and testing the command, it worked as expected. Is there something about the algorithm?

It is worth noting that the original key pair was generated by AWS.

Comment: What is the content of first line of your private key?

Comment: `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` did you mean the first line of the actual cipher?

Comment: This is odd, from where you get this key?

Comment: Are you sure you don't get your public key? Curve algorithms (like ed25519) generate very short keys (a public key can be less than 70 bytes). Have you actually tried to use the resulting string as an SSH public key entry?

Comment: @Lacek that was it. please add it as an answer so I can upvote it. meybe it will help someone else in the future. At least my hunch about the algorithm was right